# Wmic ,all of the valid clause behind the where keyword

Tags: where-clause, wmic, clause

I want to know the all of the valid clauses behind where keyword about wmic command.

```
Wmic nicconfig where DefaultIPGateway!='' get description
```

The above command sentence show me an error message `description = invalid query`

I suspect that the `DefaultIPGateway` is not a valid clause. So how to get the all of the valid clauses behind the where keyword.

I did the following tries.

```
Wmic alias get pwhere
```

Answer (score 1):

Full list of the WQL keywords: [WQL (SQL for WMI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx).

[Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **DefaultIPGateway**
>
> Data type: `string array` 
> Access type: Read-only 
> Qualifiers:
>   MappingStrings
>   ("Win32Registry|System\CurrentControlSet\Services|Parameters|DefaultGateway")
>
> **Array** of IP addresses of default gateways that the computer system uses.

[Querying with WQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The WMI Query Language (WQL) is a subset of standard American National
>   Standards Institute Structured Query Language (ANSI SQL) with minor
>   semantic changes to support WMI.
>
> …
>
> Note  **WQL does not support queries of `array` datatypes**.

**Corollary**: you cannot constitute a valid `WHERE` clause to narrow the `wmic` output by `DefaultIPGateway` data.

Please read http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html to see some valid `WHERE` clause examples used in `wmic` command.

However, you can still get desired info using [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) commands, for instance as follows:

```
==> Wmic nicconfig get DefaultIPGateway, description | find "{"
{"192.168.11.1"}   Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```